# Tax query array terms display out of order

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, array, order, tax-query

I want my tax_query terms to display posts in the order I have them listed in the array below but it is not following the order listed.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'staff',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'staff-title',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array(
                                'editor-in-chief',
                                'managing-editor',
                                'fiction-editor',
                                'poetry-editor',
                                'nonfiction-editor',
                                'production-manager'
                            )
            )
        )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();


                echo'<div class="loop four columns">';
                    echo'<div class="column-nest">';
                        echo'<h5 class="staff-title big-top-space">'; the_field('staff_title'); echo'</h5>';
                        echo'<h6 class="staff-name  bottom-space">'; the_field('staff_member_name'); echo'</h6>';               
                    echo'</div> <!-- column-nest -->';
                    echo'<figure class="staff-photo-border">';
                        echo'<img class="column-nest" src="'; the_field('staff_member_photo'); echo'" alt="photo of the_field(\'staff_member_name\');" />';
                    echo'</figure> <!-- staff-photo-border -->';
                echo'</div> <!-- loop four columns -->';


    the_content();
 endwhile; endif; ?>
```

instead it displays posts in this order:

Fiction Editor
Fiction Editor
Poetry Editor
Poetry Editor
Nonfiction Editor
Production Manager
Managing Editor
Editor-in-Chief

Comment: Do you expect posts to be ordered in the order that you provide in the `terms` array?

Comment: With Wordpress I've come to expect nothing - but yes that's what I was hoping/searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr;

This is not possible with `tax_query`.

A `tax_query` is a restriction of the results delivered, not used to order posts. You use the [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for that.

#### A little excursion into statistics

This has to do with statistics and mathematics, as a taxonomy is a [nominal scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Nominal_scale), meaning it is just a classification, where every item is on the same level. Like the color of an eye - you can't say which is better just with this data.

To order data you have to have some kind of a comparison between the data. This is called the [ordinal scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ordinal_scale), (yeah, the word order is in ordinal), for example 3 is bigger than 2 is bigger than 1, therefor you can order them with the smallest or the biggest first (`ASC` and `DESC`). Please note that `title` also follows an ordinal scale, but not by comparison of the content, but by the scale of the alphabet.

*to be complete, there are also the [interval scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Interval_scale) and the [ratio scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale), but those have nothing to do with the WordPress Query.

#### Back to WordPress

Now as we learned that you can not order a taxonomy (without Metadata), you can just use it to define a group of characteristics the result should have.

In the `tax_query` you define a set of characteristics a post should have, nothing more. Please not that a set could also be a restriction like `NOT IN`.

After you defined the restrictions with `tax_query` (and, to be fair, `meta_query` does the same thing with different data), you can tell WordPress how to order your results, based on a measurable variable (be it an integer, alphabetical or any other ordinal scale).

This happens by adding

```
    'order' => 'ASC', // Order Ascending
    'orderby' => 'title', // Order by Title
```

to your `$args` array.

### a possible solution

One thing you could do, however, is querying your restrictions in sequence, not all together.
Please note that this approach is heavier for the database.

In my example I use an array to define the order of my taxonomies, and loop through this array, querying every taxonomy on it's own.

*By putting the taxonomies into an ordered array, I added a ordinal capability to it. The taxonomy itself is still nominal.*

```
$taxonomies = array(
    'editor-in-chief',
    'managing-editor',
    'fiction-editor',
    'poetry-editor',
    'nonfiction-editor',
    'production-manager'
);
foreach( $taxonomies as $thistaxonomy ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'staff',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'staff-title',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array(
                    $thistaxonomy
                )
            )
        )
    );
    
    /* All your query and magic down there */

}
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks @fischi, works great! I appreciate the explanation too. BTW, not to be a nuisance, just for the sake of best practices, should I avoid setting this up the way I did, is there perhaps better way to have gone about it?

Comment: Not if you want to have them displayed like you do. at least none I can think of ;)